# want to autogenerate Id value prepended with user provided string with jpa or hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

my code is :-

```
@Id
//@SequenceGenerator(name = "non_distributor", sequenceName="nd")
@GeneratedValue

public int getNondistid()
{
    return nondistid;
}
public void setNondistid(int nondistid) 
{
    this.nondistid = nondistid;
}
```

it is generating id value in numbers as 1, 2,3 but i want that the Auto Generated Id must be like:-  " nd_01" or "nd1".
So kindly give advice how to generate the same using annotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="fooId")
private Integer id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class News implements Serializable {

   @Id   
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;
}

TABLE SQL::
create table News (id bigint not null primary key (id));
```

Comment: tried this but not generating the desired id value...I want to generate id value as   "nd_1" suppose for nondistributor id